# Print numbers with 4 decimal places on a single line

Tags: c++

Is there a way to print numbers in a single line and regardless of anything?

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<iomanip>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    int main()
    {
        double r;
        double n = 3.14159;
        cin >> r;
        cout << "A=";
        cout << std :: fixed;
        cout << std :: setprecision(4);
        cout << n * r * r << "\n";
        return 0;
    }
```

As in python which is only:

```
print("Hello {0:.4f}".format(a))
```

look and I can't find the way

Comment: The C++ puritans will hate me for this ... but you *can* use `printf` - which is very versatile in terms of its formatting options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `std::cout`, you can just combine them with the `<<` operator like this:

```
cout << "A=" << std :: fixed << std :: setprecision(4) << n * r * r << "\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

C++20 will let you use [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) for a very similar syntax to python:

```
double a = 4.2;
std::cout << std::format("Hello {0:.4f}\n", a);
```

Comment: Doesn't look like any compiler supports `format` yet? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

Comment: In the meantime, there is [boost::format](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/format/)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer it is my fault I did not say that it should be in c ++ 17

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include<bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    
    int main() {
        double r;
        double n = 3.14159;
        cin >> r;
        double a;
        a = n*r*r;
        cout<<"A = ";
        printf("%.4f",a);
        return 0;
    }
```

include header file of bits/stdc++.h

Comment: It seems very good to me but when I upload it and when a judge reviews it, he tells me a presentation error

Comment: please give me some detail about judge where your are uploading it so that I can provide you proper solution. Because I have tested this code with input it was working fine

Comment: this is my exercise and here is the judge https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1021